# Why DNN response the given module(the Module that I created) is currently unavailable

Tags: dotnetnuke

Hiiii...,
I am new to **DNN** and am using DNN v-9.9, some one has given me a compiled DNN module but am not able to install it in my DNNSite- it throws too many Exceptions....something like the ff <=++++=>The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.

With 100% Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have the source code for the module, too!

From your description, it's a bit difficult to interpret the problem.  But, the Admin Logs provide one level of information.  You may find additional information in the files located in Portals/_default/logs.

There error you mentioned may be an indication that there are some files missing.

It may also be that this module was built for an ee

Answer (score 0):

When create installable module package, it need to include all the missing library the project reference to. such as those Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

If you're using Christoc template, you have to modify the buildscript to include it when build on Release.